# Multisite - maximum number of users with specific role

Tags: plugins, multisite, users, user-roles, count

Is there any plugin or script where i can use to define maximum number of users with a specific role on subsite in a multisite network?

I'm offering cloud helpdesk wordpress and pricing is based on number of agents, so I want to make sure that site admin is not able to add more agents than the predefined.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is how I did it:

```
add_action( 'editable_roles' , 'hide_editable_roles' );
function hide_editable_roles( $roles ){
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); // Get current subsite id
switch($blog_id) { // Define different max agents numbers depending on subsite id
    case 6: 
    $max_agents = 10; //for subsite id#6 we can have maximum 10 agents
     break;  
    case 7: //for subsite id#7 we can have maximum 3 agents
    $max_agents = 3;
    break;  
    default:
    $max_agents = 3000; //default is 3000 agents
    break;
}
  $agents = get_users( array( 'role' => 'agent' ) ); // here you define the role
  $agents = count( $agents );
    if ($max_agents <= $agents){
        unset( $roles['agent'] ); // here you define the role
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

Comment: Quite indeed, good call. I totally forgot `editable_roles` filter's existance.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** There was a problem with my previous code based on some erroneous digging into WordPress roles and capabilities. The below code should work a little better now.

You could maybe try hooking the `map_meta_cap` filter, something like this might work:

```php
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'has_max_agents', 10, 2 );

function has_max_agents( $caps, $cap ) {
    static $max_agents = 30; // Example max number of agents.
    if ( 'create_users' !== $cap ) {
        return $caps;
    }

    $users = get_users( [
        'role__in' => [ 'agent' ], // Your custom role in place of 'agent'
    ] );

    if ( true || $max_agents <= count( $users ) ) {
        foreach ( $caps as $index => $maybe_remove_cap ) {
            if ( 'create_users' !== $maybe_remove_cap ) {
                continue;
            }

            unset( $caps[ $index ] );
        }
    }

    $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';

    return $caps;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't work, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [insert_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/insert_user_meta/) (inside `wp_insert_user()`, which is also called by `wp_update_user()`) could also be a viable method to block extra agents from being registered. [set_user_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_user_role/) action might also be needed to prevent existing users from getting an agent role.

```
// Maybe prevent setting new users to agent role
function new_user_check_roles( $meta, $user, $update ) {

  $max_agents = 30;
  $agents = get_users( array( 'role' => 'agent' ) );
  $agents = count( $agents );

  if ( $max_agents != $agents ) {
    return $meta;
  }

  if ( in_array( 'agent', $user->roles ) ) {
    $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );
  }

  if ( isset( $meta['role'] ) && 'agent' == $meta['role'] ) {
    $meta['role'] = 'subscriber';
  }  

  return $meta;
}
add_filter( 'insert_user_meta', 'new_user_check_roles', 10, 3 );

// Maybe prevent setting existing user to agent role
function set_roles_check_role( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ) {

  $max_agents = 30;
  $agents = get_users( array( 'role' => 'agent' ) );
  $agents = count( $agents );

  if ( $max_agents != $agents ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( 'agent' !== $role ) {
    return;
  }

  $user = new WP_User( user_id );
  $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );
}
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'set_roles_check_role', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't work, thanks though.

Comment: forgot to mention it's a multisite network, not sure if this is the reason why it didn't work

Comment: @Akram Are the users created in the subsite (by administrator) or the network (by super admin) user view?

Comment: They are created by the subsite administrator

Comment: @Akram Yes, lets discuss more on LinkedIn.